# NOT EXISTS together with SELECT NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out what this SQL query is doing, more specifically in the part that starts after `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    order_num,
    MIN(order_date)
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    order_date >= '01.01.2019'
    AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            result
        WHERE
            unique_id = '201895'
            AND
            result = order_num
    )
GROUP BY
    order_num
```

Comment: You miss information about the database schema

Comment: @mathguy My mistake. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Does `NULL`, specifically, in the `SELECT` clause of the subquery, bother you? Or is it the whole `NOT EXISTS` part of the query? You already have a correct explanation of `NULL` in one of the posted answers.

Comment: It's the whole NOT EXISTS part that I don't fully understand. What does it exactly try to do?

Answer (score 8):

`SELECT NULL` still returns rows from the query. It does the same as if it was:

`[...] EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [...]`

or

`[...] EXISTS( SELECT Id FROM [...]`

It's just one way to make it clear that the value is not used.

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` checks to see if rows are returned.  It does not care what is in the result -- even `NULL`.  I am definitely not a fan of using it.  I tend to use `1` -- easier to type and clearer.

That said, the query should be using table aliases and qualified column names.  This can be very important with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT o.order_num, MIN(o.order_date)
FROM orders o
WHERE o.order_date >= DATE '2019-01-01' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM result r
                  WHERE r.unique_id = '201895' and
                        r.result = o.order_num
                 )
GROUP BY o.order_num;
```

I also fixed the date constant to use the `DATE` keyword.  This is safer than relying on database settings.

Comment: I think using "NULL" in exists/not exists is clearer than using a constant; it indicates you're selecting nothing, rather than selecting something. At least, to me it does!

Comment: @Boneist . . . I can't wrap my mind around `NULL` meaning that something exists in SQL.  It very often used to mean that values are missing or that an outer join did not succeed.  Kudos that you feel differently.  I hope you can appreciate why others find it misleading.

Comment: Aha, it's literally just popped into my head why others might prefer to select a constant - to me, an exists/not exists check just looks at the predicates; it's ignoring the select part completely, so to make it clear, I use NULL. However, if you're looking at the subquery first and then doing the exists (which isn't (afaik) how Oracle handles the exists check), I could see selecting a constant might be preferable. I'm still sticking with NULL, though! *{;-)

Comment: @Boneist I'm happy to use `select *`. As you say, it won't _actually_ select anything, and it's definitely not how Oracle treats it. I do see the use of constants more often nowadays, but apparently that's because not every database optimizes this as well as Oracle does.